Access to files, directories and subdirectories
I'm trying to access all files, directories and subdirectories within a directory in the $HOME directory in a Tauri App (Svelte as frontend, but I don't think that matter).
The file system looks something like
$HOME
  - project-dir
    - file.txt
    - .hidden
      - config.json

I need to have access to everything inside the project-dir directory.
My capabilities.json looks like
 "permissions": [
        "fs:default",
        {
            "identifier": "fs:scope",
            "allow": [
                {
                    "path": "$HOME/project-dir/**"
                },
                {
                    "path": "$HOME/project-dir/**/*"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]

I manage to read files in the project-dir directory, but not nested files (Unhandled Promise Rejection: forbidden path), and also apparentyle I haven't allowed the use of the fs.watch function
Unhandled Promise Rejection: fs.watch not allowed

When accessing the files I use the path API to create the path to files, but still can't access that nested config.json file.
Anyone can help me configuring the capabilities file?

option1
change the path patterns
{
    "identifier": "fs:scope",
    "allow": [
        {
            "path": "$HOME/project-dir"
        },
        {
            "path": "$HOME/project-dir/**"
        }
    ]
}

with $HOME/project-dir/** project-dir will not get matched, only it's children will get allowed.
option 2
change the permission scope to a more specific command scope
{
    "identifier": "fs:allow-home-read-recursive",
    "allow": [
        {
            "path": "$HOME/project-dir/**/*"
        },
    ]
}

